# Parcelable class and ArrayLists in Android

Tags: android, rotation

In my app I read data from a database which I created. Everything works fine apart from rotation. When I rotate the phone I don't get any exceptions,but the webservice is run again and I do not want that. After some research I found out that my model class should implement the Parcelable interface. Here is what I did according to google's android guide site.

```
public class FootballNewsObject implements Parcelable{
String title;
String article;
String image;

public FootballNewsObject() {

}

public FootballNewsObject(Parcel in) {
    title = in.readString();
    article = in.readString();
    image = in.readString();
}


public void setArticle(String article) {
    this.article = article;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getArticle() {
    return article;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}



@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeString(article);
    dest.writeString(image);
}
public static final Creator<FootballNewsObject> CREATOR = new Creator<FootballNewsObject>() {
    @Override
    public FootballNewsObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        Log.v("Theo","Create from parser: Movies");
        return new FootballNewsObject(in);
    }

    @Override
    public FootballNewsObject[] newArray(int size) {
        return new FootballNewsObject[size];
    }
 };
}
```

And of course I have a fragment where I am taking care of the views and the actual webservice using the Volley Library.

```
public class FootballNews extends Fragment {

public static final String TAG = "ManuApp";
private static final String IMAGE_URL = "my link goes here" ;
private static final String FL_NEWS ="FL NEWS" ;
private List<FootballNewsObject> listItemsList;

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private FootballNewsAdapter adapter;

public FootballNews() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_football_news, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    listItemsList = new ArrayList<FootballNewsObject>();
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    //mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(getActivity()).color(Color.BLACK).build());
    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        listItemsList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(FL_NEWS);
    }
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    updateList();


}
public void updateList() {

    listItemsList.clear();


    //declare the adapter and attach it to the recyclerview
    adapter = new FootballNewsAdapter(getActivity(), listItemsList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    // Clear the adapter because new data is being added from a new subreddit
    //adapter.clearAdapter();

    //showPD();

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    JsonArrayRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, Config.URL_FOOTBALL_NEWS, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            //hidePD();

            // Parse json data.
            // Declare the json objects that we need and then for loop through the children array.
            // Do the json parse in a try catch block to catch the exceptions
            try {



                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject post = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    FootballNewsObject item = new FootballNewsObject();
                    item.setTitle(post.getString("title"));
                    item.setImage(IMAGE_URL + post.getString("news_image"));
                    item.setArticle(post.getString("article"));



                    listItemsList.add(item);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Update list by notifying the adapter of changes
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //hidePD();
        }
    });
    jsObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
        @Override
        public int getCurrentTimeout() {
            return 50000;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
            return 50000;
        }

        @Override
        public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

        }
    });
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);

}


protected boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putParcelableArrayList(FL_NEWS, (ArrayList<? extends  
    Parcelable>) listItemsList);
  }
}
```

As you can see I am using to store my list's data in Parcelable

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putParcelableArrayList(FL_NEWS, (ArrayList<? extends    
    Parcelable>) listItemsList);
}
```

And if the savedInstance is not null just get the data.

```
   if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        listItemsList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(FL_NEWS);
    }
```

But as I said in the beginning,the webservice is running again after rotation. What should I do to stop that?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I tried this but still have the same propblem

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(gottaGettaList = (savedInstanceState==null)) {
        updateList();
    }else{
        gottaGettaList=false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onActivityCreated()` calls `updateList()`. In `updateList()`, you always invoke the Web service. If you do not want to always invoke the Web service, change `updateList()` to use an `if` test to decide whether or not to invoke the Web service.

For example, if your rule is "if we are coming back from a configuration change, do not invoke the Web service", then you could:

Step #1: Add a `boolean gottaGettaList` parameter to `updateList()`

Step #2: Call `updateList(savedInstanceState==null)` in `onActivityCreated()`

Step #3: In `updateList()`, only invoke the Web service if `gottaGettaList` is `true`.

Comment: Please at look my editted code. Rotation can be so confusing:(

Comment: @Theo: You cannot skip `updateList()` entirely, as that is where you are putting the list into the adapter. However, you should skip all the Volley-related code. BTW, I forgot that `onActivityCreated()` had the `Bundle`, so I simplified my steps.

Comment: So you mean to put an if statement in my update list method where I have my adapter?

Comment: All I want is to stop the webservice running after rotation and display the stored data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I fixed it,as the webservice in not running twice:)

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState==null) {
            updateList();
        }else{
            adapter = new FootballNewsAdapter(getActivity(), listItemsList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}
```

During rotation I am attaching my adapter again:). Without attaching the adapter inside the else statement I was getting a blank screen and a message.

```
 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```